# How can i prove that a graph is bipartite?

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

I know the theory and the lemma that says if a graph contains an odd length cycle then it cant be bipartite but how can i PROVE it?

[image]

take for example this
adjacency matrix how can i prove that this graph is or isnt bipartite?

Comment: I don't think that that graph is bipartite, is it?

Comment: it is, but i cant prove it

Comment: I can get from any node to any other node, so how is it bipartite?

Comment: a bipartite graph (or bigraph) is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint and independent sets U and V such that every edge connects a vertex in U to one in V

Comment: Ah, I misremebered the definiont.

Comment: Well the two groups are {2, 5} and {1, 3, 4, 6}, does that help?

Comment: I know that this graph is bipartite and the groups, but i must use an algorithm to prove that this graph is bipartite

Comment: There's a number of ways to do it, you could 1) find every cycle and check that there are no odd cycle lengths.  Or 2) try to apply two-coloring and see if it fails, or 3) determine the two sets and then confirm that they meet th4e requirements (i.e., only connect to the other set).  Personally I think that 3 is the easiest.  Hmm, though I guess that (2) and (3) are actually fairly equivalent algorithms.

Comment: You'd like to show `if a graph contains an odd cycle in can't be bipartite`. Because the definition of a bipartite graph is a little clunky (tricky to negate) it's easier to prove the contrapositive: `if a graph is bipartite it doesn't contain an odd cycle`. I think this hint is enough to get you started on a proof.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the algorithm I would use.  It uses approach (3) that I mentioned in the comments above: determine the two sets and confirm that they meet the requirements (i.e., each vertex only connects to the other set)

```
  1) Make two sets, group1 and group2.  
     Mark all of the vertexes as unassigned and incomplete

  2) Assign the first unassigned vertex to group1 and make it the current vertex

  3) For every assigned vertex connected to the current vertex (both to and from):
    a) If the current vertex is unassigned, 
           then assign the current vertex to the other group
    b) If the current vertex is assigned to the same group, 
           then the graph is not bipartite, EXIT

  4) If the current vertex is still unassigned then assign it to group1
  5) For every unassigned vertex connected to the current vertex (both to and from):
    a) assign it to the other group
  6) Mark the current vertex as complete

  7) Make the first incomplete assigned vertex the current vertex
    a) If there are none, then make the first unassigned vertex the current vertex
    b) If there are none, then the graph is bipartite.  EXIT

  8) GoTo (3)
```

If you use the Adjacency Matrix then this is probably `O(v^2)` where `v` is the number of vertices.  If you change it to a list of vertices with To/From connection lists attached then I think that it is `O(v+c)` where `c` is the number of connections.